# Why does $ 1 + \frac 13 . \frac 14 + \frac 15 . \frac 1{4^2} + \frac 17 . \frac 1{4^3} + ..... = \log 3 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

$ 1 + \frac 13 . \frac 14 + \frac 15 . \frac 1{4^2} + \frac 17 . \frac 1{4^3} + ...$

I evaluated the expression for the first few terms and I find that this number will probably tend to $ \log 3 $. I'd like to know why, or how I can prove that it does indeed tend to $ \log 3 $. **More importantly**, I'd like to know the relationship between this particular type of a series and the natural logarithm of numbers.

Why does the natural logarithm of a number show up in such a series?

Comment: Looks like: $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{4^r(2r+1)}}$$

Comment: The general term is $[(2n+1)4^n]^{-1}$ if that helps.

Comment: The reason $\log$ appears is simple: its derivative is $\frac1x$, which is exactly what allows you to get all the odd numbers to appear in the denominators..

Comment: You should be careful about writing $+\dots\infty$, it looks like you're adding infinity to all the other fractions.  This, however, is not what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your series is:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^n}{2n+1}$$
with $x = \dfrac{1}{4}.$ The standard way to go about this kind of problem is to observe that $f(x)$ only converges uniformly for $|x|\leq r<1$ for any such $r$ and then manipulate the series into something we know already, usually involving taking derivatives.

If you want the challenge, then let me give you a hint: For $0<x<1$, consider $xf(x^2)$ and then take its derivative to get something you can easily calculate.

Comment: @J.G. you are right, that was a mistake.